# Powershell out username from win32_userprofile localpath

Tags: powershell-4.0

Ok, I am trying to pull only the username out of the localpath properties of the following command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class win32_UserProfile -Filter "localPath like 'c:\\Users\\%'" | sort localpath).localpath.replace('C:\Users\','')
```

This replaces the c:\Users\ that I don't need. However, at the end of some of the names, there is a .000 or the domain name. For the life of me, I can't not remember how to remove all items after a character. If you know a better way to do this please let me know.

Output:

```
sfricks
sguess.001
sholcombe
srabanal.000
srainey.OPR.000
ssanders
sspecht.OPR
```

I can use the split option, however, it takes it from a single line of code to 3+.

```
$Return = @()
$usernames = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class win32_UserProfile -Filter "localPath like 'c:\\Users\\%'" -ErrorAction Stop | sort localpath).localpath.replace('C:\Users\','')
foreach ($user in $usernames) {
    $Return += $user.Split('.')[0]
}
$Return
```

I am trying to find the workaround using -replace. I'm not too sure how to do it yet. Just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could `-split` on the character (period, I think, in this case...)

Comment: Split would require me to rotate through each item while replace can do it in a single swop. I used replace to remove the c:\users\ information, and I know it can do the same for the .OPR.000 information as well, but I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: OH! Just dot the result with the next `replace()` - `$foo.replace('bar','').replace('quux','')`

Comment: That's what I am Trying to do @JeffZeitlin However, I can't seem to get past . being a wild. $Usernames.replace(".*","") is what I have tired and it does not work. I don't know how to wild past a wild. I'm missing something small. when I use the ".","" it only takes away the . and not everything else in following.

Comment: Ah. Then you might want to use the `-replace` operator instead, which can use regular expressions. I'd have to look it up to be sure, but I think you'd want to do something like `$foo.replace('C:\Users\','') -replace '\..*$',''`, where `\.` is the literal dot, `.*` is any number of additional characters, and `$` is the end of string.

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre is a decent cheat sheet for regular expressions. If `.replace()` is acting like it's treating `.` as a special character, try escaping it with ``\``

Comment: That's crazy. I did the '\..*$','' with .replace and it would not work. -replace works with it. mind = blown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you need to catch variable text for replacement, you're probably better off using regular expressions and the `-replace` operator instead of the `.replace()` method. For your purposes, after doing the `.replace('C:\Users\','')`, use `-replace '\..*$',''`. The decomposition of the expression is as follows:

```
\.     - Literal dot. The . is normally a special character meaning 'match anything';
         the \ escapes it and removes the special meaning.
  .*   - Match any number of any character. The dot takes on its special character
         meaning here, and the star says 'any number of the previous character'
    $  - End of string.
```

There's a good cheat sheet for regular expressions at https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre

Comment: Thank you again. Works perfectly.

Comment: At your convenience, you should click on the check; it notes that the answer worked and solved your problem. (It also throws me a little more rep.)